# Is it appropriate to ask for database design review here?

Tags: discussion

There's codereview stackexchange to ask to get.. well your code reviewed :D. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be anything equivalent for database reviewing.

Would it be appropriate to put database/schema design here with Model / EER diagram and ask for a review on it?

Comment: I think I've seen DB design review questions on Stack Overflow. I'm not sure if a purely review question would be OK either here or on SO, but it might be all right if you tried giving it a turn of a problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do questions about database design be considered apropriate ?](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56/do-questions-about-database-design-be-considered-apropriate)

Comment: CodeReview takes some database design questions (e.g. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9029/database-design-review-tracking-of-many-statuses). Meta CR: [Are database design reviews in scope?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149/are-database-design-reviews-in-scope). (Do *not* try it on Stack Overflow unless there's a specific problem you're trying to solve.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of questions are allowed on Database Administrators ?](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-kind-of-questions-are-allowed-on-database-administrators)

Answer (score 7):

I think there are two types of database design questions. There is the actual questions such as "I'm trying to work out a database design for ...." and very nit picky questions of "I have this database design and I was wondering what you guys think about it". The later will result mostly in opinions and not really a useful entry in a Q&A forum.

E.g. [Can Anyone please review my database after I did the Normalization ?.Any suggestion is appreciated](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57524/can-anyone-please-review-my-database-after-i-did-the-normalization-any-suggest)

It is hard to give a definite answer to the question asked. Hence so far there are only comments. That's really what the person is after when asking this question - he wants input from others so he can make his final decision, so you will see mostly comments as answer, since it's not really a question.

The question being "can anyone please review.." the answer is "Yes" or "No" :)

So I think that type of question does not belong.

But there has been other good database design questions too which I think would belong as they provide good data for others to use in the future.

[Is it important to design the database the right way from the beginning?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57514/is-it-important-to-design-the-database-the-right-way-from-the-beginning)

[Best design for a many:many relationship issue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57284/best-design-for-a-manymany-relationship-issue)

Answer (score 0):

No – use [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Personally, as a convert to the ways of maintaining database schemas as code (scripts), I'm firmly of the belief that databases *are* (in many ways) code.

Comment: The actual advice on [Code Review meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149/are-database-design-reviews-in-scope) is a little more nuanced than that.  As a philosophical question, database schemas _can_ be code, but they certainly are not _just_ code.

Comment: @JonEricson – when a co-founder of the Stack Exchange family of sites writes "I would say this is in the correct spirit of code review, provided the relevant schemas are provided in the question.", then I think it's pretty straightforward and mostly lacking in nuance. Aside from any "philosophical question", what exactly is it about database schemas that is significantly different from other examples of code that is pertinent to this question?

Comment: A create script is code. A database design is not.

Comment: The design of code, for both 'real' code or a database 'create script' (or a SQL query) is to varying degrees *implied*. I'm pretty sure 'code reviews' aren't strictly limited to claiming whether code works or not, so the same should apply to database designs. Some context about the code that will use the database would be useful, just like the same would be useful when discussing the design of a 'regular' API.